# Incorporate a PDF map in Swift app with panning, zooming, and tapping

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am looking for some assistance incorporating a PDF map of a metro system into my Swift UIKit app.

I have tried saving the PDF map as an asset and loading it into an ImageView. This behaves as expected with zooming (whether by pinch-to-zoom or double-tapping) and panning working flawlessly. However, the quality of the zoomed in image is degraded/blurry

I have tried loading the PDF map into the project files directly and calling upon it in a PDFView (via PDFKit). This fixes the blurriness, but there is a specific issue with panning I can't seem to resolve. If I pan the zoomed map diagonally, it works as expected. If I pan the zoomed map vertically, it seems to lock the panning to a vertical axis until I release my finger. Likewise if I pan the zoomed map horizontally, it locks the panning to a horizontal axis until I release my finger. I have tried a WebView as well but it seems to have the same panning issue as the PDFView

Is there a way to implement this PDF map such that it behaves like the ImageView behavior I described, but maintains the sharpness/clarify as in the PDFView? I suppose I can convert the PDF into a high-quality PNG, but that would significantly increase the size of my app and I would like to avoid that if possible

I do also want to allow the user to access information about a tapped station in the future, so a method that allows for (eventually) retrieving tapped coordinates would be best. Thank you

Comment: When you add a PDF to your app, it is rendered as an image at build time. That means that it has fixed resolution and zoom is going to be blurry. PDFView renders the image at run time, which is why zoom works.

Comment: @Paulw11 ah I did not know that. Is there any way to increase the fixed resolution? Or to fix the panning issue described with the PDFView?

Comment: The behaviour you are describing with PDFView panning seems to be by design - If you start a drag left/right or up/down gesture then the PDFView locks the axis.  If you start a pan gesture by dragging diagonally then it allows free panning.  You could submit feedback to Apple developer support that this behaviour should be customisable. Whether your render your PDF as a high resolution image yourself or somehow get the compiler to do it at build time, it will have the same impact on your app size.